# How to style a table to look like gridview

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table created in `HTML` inside a `<div>` tag. Below is the code of the table:

```
<div id="cont-lef">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="5px" border="1" id="myGridStyle">
       <tr>
          <td><p>Sunday Mornings</td>          
          <td><p>Rs 2.5 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Saturday &Sunday Afternoons</td>          
          <td><p>Rs 2.0 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Weekdays  </td>
          <td><p>Rs 1.5 lakhs + ST</td>          
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><p>Tournament Management</td>          
          <td><p>Rs. 25,000 + ST</td>          
       </tr>        
       <tr>
          <td><p>Caddy Fee</td>          
          <td><p>Rs. 300 per caddy</td>          
       </tr>                     
    </table>
</div>
```

Now I want to style this using `CSS` to look like a `GridView`. I don't need any *pagination* or *search options* of the grid. I just want to change all even rows to have green color and the border like a grid. How can I do this?

Comment: Please define `GridView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to point out that your **HTML is invalid**, you are not closing any of the `p` tags.. so consider doing that first.. As far as the selecting of even rows go, you can use `:nth-` pseudo like

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
   background: green;
}
```

And about the grid view, I believe that you want *dotted border lines* for your `table` so you should use

```
table tr td {
   border: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPmkQ/)

Don't forget to `collapse` the `table` borders using

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: Looks like `border-collapse:collapse` did the nice look :) +1

Comment: Why should we give `border-collapse:collapse`

Comment: @user3004356 any reason for accepting and unaccepting answer again and again?

Comment: sorry it happened by mistake

Comment: @user3004356 It's fine, I thought you were expecting something else so I could've helped so pinged :)

Answer (score 1):

For `even` rows to have `green` color, just do:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: what about the gridview look. Can you suggest me something

Comment: I don't need any pagination/search options. But I want it to look like a simple gridview

Comment: @user3004356: Please define what is `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr:nth-child(odd){background : green}
tr, td{border:1px solid #999}
```

And also remove "*border = 1*" from html

**[Fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WLMu/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I thought when u wanted gridview you meant like Android grid view? Boxes of stuff?

http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/2yFeb/2/

```
table {
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #f00;
    padding:20px;
    width:200px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaa;
}
```

Not sure if this is what you are after. Please change colors/values/remove shadows if you want.

Also a note, you might want to close your < p > tags. And since you want to use css, might as well remove some attributes in the < table > tag.